# how to reduce the thickness of default bootstrap icon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try the icon glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right for showing the direction in my design but I need some thin than default size.
So how to reduce the thickness of default bootstrap icon of glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right
My code was:-

```
  <div style="color:#FFF;">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current bootstrap has more icons including a thinner arrow called `glyphicon-menu-right`.

You could always look for an alternative icon font. There are literally dozens out there - some for free. Or hire someone to create the icons you need. Or do it yourself, for example with [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io).

Answer (score 1):

You can alter css of all bootstrap glyphicons very easily. Like in this case font-size and font-weight of classes `.glyphicon` & `.glyphicon-chevron-right` can be reduced to your desired size

Answer (score 0):

I try to find a solution for this too. I will search for something better, but until now I replaced the icon with .fa-chevron-down that is a little thinner than .glyphicon-chevron-right.

Answer (score -2):

Just set `width` and `heigth` properties for your icon. But be sure that you change your icon dimensions in proportion one to dimension to other